# css flex-grow on image while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I want to make 4 buttons and an image (live stream) appear on screen at the same time, without overflow and on mobile or pc. I also want the image to be as large as it can be, without pushing the buttons out of the boundries of their container, in my case the container in the body. At the moment i have this code but the image doesn't keep its' aspect ratio. I obviously also don't want it to be cut off at the edges or anything alike.

```css
html, body, .container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    background-color: purple;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

button {
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    background-color: red;
    border-width: 7px;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 10%;
}


.arrow {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 .5em .5em 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .8em;
}

.up {
    transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-.4em) translateX(-.4em);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-.4em) translateX(-.4em);
}

.down {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-.4em) translateX(-.4em);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-.4em) translateX(-.4em);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>Microscope Controller</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="static/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <span>
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="live-image" />
            </span>
            <button id="move-up"><d class="arrow up"></d></button>

            <button id="move-down"><d class="arrow down"></d></button>

            <button id="set-start"></button>

            <button id="set-end"></button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use flex wrap if you don't want to push the buttons in next row

Comment: You have given the boxes 10em width. What do you to happen if the viewport is too narrow to accommodate them without overflow?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this is what you're looking for, but I will try to answer based on my understanding of the issue. Keeping the `img` separately instead of wrapped in a `span` tag should help maintain its aspect ratio. Further instead of giving the buttons a fixed height and width you should try giving them `flex: 1;` and set the width to `max-width` with an `aspect-ratio: 1;`, which will ensure they maintain their dimensions. Also, as mentioned above you can remove the `flex-wrap: wrap;` to prevent the buttons from wrapping to the next line. Have edited your code, hope it helps.

```css
html, body, .container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    background-color: purple;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

button {
    flex: 1;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    max-width: 10em;
    background-color: red;
    border-width: 7px;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 10%;
}


.arrow {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 .5em .5em 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .8em;
}

.up {
    transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-.4em) translateX(-.4em);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-.4em) translateX(-.4em);
}

.down {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-.4em) translateX(-.4em);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-.4em) translateX(-.4em);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>Microscope Controller</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="static/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="live-image" />

            <button id="move-up"><d class="arrow up"></d></button>

            <button id="move-down"><d class="arrow down"></d></button>

            <button id="set-start"></button>

            <button id="set-end"></button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, though the buttons have lost all style and the image doesn't grow even though it could. The wrap is intentional, so that they appear on the bottom on mobile phones

Comment: nevermind, you just removed the css link. After reattaching it, the image still doesn't grow and doesn't shrink when the viewport gets too small either

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you want from the question. You should at least attach a screenshot. I gave an example when the picture occupies the entire space and the buttons are close to each other. (Slightly reduced the size of the buttons for example).

```css
html, body, .container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-color: purple;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container>span {
  flex: auto;
}

.container>span>img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 7px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  flex: none;
}

.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 .5em .5em 0;
  display: block;
  padding: .8em;
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-.4em) translateX(-.4em);
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-.4em) translateX(-.4em);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/600" id="live-image" />
  </span>
  <button id="move-up"><d class="arrow up"></d></button>
  <button id="move-down"><d class="arrow down"></d></button>
  <button id="set-start"></button>
  <button id="set-end"></button>
</div>
```